# '"file" argument must be a non-empty string' error when using playStream()

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I am encountering a problem with the `playStream()` function.
The stream does not play and I get the following error:

```
"file" argument must be a non-empty string
```

And yes, I am sure that `args[0]` is defined as `'youtube.com/watch?v=A02s8omM_hI'` and `stream` logs as a `PassThrough` ([console](https://pastebin.com/k3jbAnVv)).

```
var stream = ytdl(args[0], { filter: "audioonly" });
message.member.voiceChannel.join().then(connection => {
   const dispatcher = connection.playStream(stream);

   dispatcher.on("error", (error) => {
      console.log(error);
   });

   dispatcher.on("end", () => {
      console.log("Song ended!");
   });
});
```

Unfortunately, I couldn't find any solutions on the internet related to my problem.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you console.log string and tell us what it is?

Comment: `args[0]` is defined as **http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A02s8omM_hI** and `console.log(stream)` returns the following: [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/k3jbAnVv)

Comment: what is args by the way?)

Comment: @JerrySmith I used `args` as an abbreviation for arguments. I split the received message into prefix, command, and arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you've passed an empty string as a output file?

[docs:](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ytdl)

> -o FILE, --output FILE         Save to file, template by {prop}, default: stdout

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'll look into it. Note that I use **ytdl-core** since it's optimized for NodeJS programs. [(ytdl-core)](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ytdl-core)